# "order by" not working with model in CakePHP 2.6 Pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to adapt this code to sort the result:

```
$result = $this->Paginate('ReceivedCargo', 
    array('PNR_BROKERS' => $id )
);`
```

I tried:

```
$result = $this->Paginate('ReceivedCargo', 
    array('PNR_BROKERS' => $id),               
    array('ReceivedCargo.PNR' => 'desc')
);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: plz tell me how to solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$this->Paginator->settings['ReceivedCargo']['conditions']['PNR_BROKERS']=$id
$this->Paginator->settings['ReceivedCargo']['order']=array(
    'ReceivedCargo.PNR' => 'DESC'
);
$result = $this->Paginator->paginate('ReceivedCargo');
```

By the way, `$this->Paginate()` is deprecated (provided for backwards compatibility). You should instead access the `PaginatorComponent` directly.

For further information, see:

- [Cookboox 2.x: Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination)